# Why is Python socket is 4.5x slower than Java socket to connect?

Tags: python, java, performance, sockets

I tested Python sockets vs Java sockets and I found out that Python takes 4.5x longer to connect to an server than Java.

Python code:

```py
import socket, time

ip = "74.125.20.147" #ip of www.google.com
port = 80

def main():
  st = time.time()
  for i in range(10000):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip, port))
  ed = time.time()
  print(ed-st)

main()
```

Java code:

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.System.*;

class test{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    long st = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0;i<10000;i++){
      Socket s = new Socket();
      s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("74.125.20.147", 80));
    }
    
    long ed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.print(ed-st);
  }
}
```

Results:

***Python: 27 seconds (27.012101888656616)***

***Java: 6 seconds (6.569)***

I don't know what is wrong. I ran both on same machine and both are connecting to the same IP.

I tried to change my python code to use classes and tried to change DNS (even thought I was connecting to an ipv4 not domain) but nothing worked.
I have tried using socket options but they didn't worked either.

Why does python takes 4.5x longer to connect since both scripts are doing the same work?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Could you add an explicit "close" of the socket to both codes and compare again? Python's standard implementation uses mainly reference counting for garbage collection and is inefficient on multithreading. This may affect how and when the implicit close operation is executed.

Comment: Python uses reference counting and might be closing the sockets each iteration, whereas Java is pure GC and will defer the closes. That could account for the difference. What if you use a `with` statement in Python and a `try`-with-resources block in Java so both are forced to close the sockets immediately? Or, alternatively, store all the Python sockets in a list so they're not closed until the program exits.

Comment: Does connecting to a host in your local network make a difference? I tested against a local network webserver and times between python3.9 and Java are both reporting 3-4 seconds

Comment: I tryed as John suggested: in Python code, the sockets are created using `with` statement, and in Java code, sockets are created using `try-with-resources` block... The results are the same... **Python: 25 seconds, Java: 6 seconds**....... I tryed to store the sockets in a list and closing them before the program exits...  The results are the same: **Python: 28 seconds, Java: 6 seconds**

Comment: @zaxishere Yes, if i connect both on localhost they have the same performance: **Python: 4 seconds | Java: 3 seconds**

Comment: Your units seem to be inconsistent.  Is it _seconds_ or _ms_ (milliseconds)?

Comment: @JimGarrison The results are in seconds, when i mentioned "(27.012101888656616 ms)" i was just being more specific

Comment: You could also test with Python 2 in order to see whether the additional `getpeername` call Python 3 makes makes a difference. I also noticed that Java used the IPv6 address "::ffff:74.125.20.147".